# UIImageView spills out of collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a uicollectionview cell with an imageView inside of it. In the cell I have two uiviews that are set to be equal heights, constrained to reach the edges of the cell, and stacked on top of each other. In the top uiview I placed a uiimageview and constrained it to it will be 10 pixels from the top, sides, and bottom.

Picture of the xib: [image]

The problem that I face is when I place an image in the view and run it this happens:

[image]

What I dont understand is why it does that. It doesnt do this when I change the color of the background leading me to suspect that the image is causing it.

Pic of no problem but without image:

[image]

Comment: Please just use StackOverflow to host your images. That way we can actually see what they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `estimate size` is set to `Automatic`. Set it to `None`

[image]